# Using stressed "the" to emphasize outstanding noun

Tags: grammaticality, articles

I'm not a native English speaker and sometimes I encounter article "the" used in stressed form before some noun or name, mostly in movies, like "That's not the gun, that's THE gun" or "He is THE specialist". Is it correct or common use of this article for emphasizing something outstanding? Is it allowed in written form?

Comment: It is perfectly correct, but in formal work it should be typographically represented in italics rather than all-caps.

Comment: ...or -- less commonly -- bold, or small caps.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Small caps are greatly preferred in proper typesetting. Bold faces are much too heavy in normal print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 'THE' emphasized draws attention to the article, stressing the fact that this is 'the' gun, as opposed to 'a' gun... in other words, it is highlighting that it is a specific gun, not simply one gun out of many.

It is generally used to point out that something is in some way exceptional or highly relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this usage, but wasn't sure